# Get Values From A Regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm building a web crawler that was set up like this:

```
url = "The URL I'm Scraping"
urls = [url] #stack of urls to scrape
visited = [url] #record of scraped urls

#while stack of urls is greater than 0, keep scraping for links
while len(urls) > 0:
    try:
        htmltext = urllib.urlopen(urls[0]).read()
#except for visited urls
    except:
        print urls[0]    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
    urls.pop(0)
#print number of urls in stack
    print len(urls)

    x = "address"
    y = re.findall(x,htmltext)

    Print y
```

That prints out all occurrences of the word "address," but doesn't get the values of "address" like it should.  I also tried a few variations of this:

```
y = re.findall(r'address="([^"]*)"',htmltext)
```

But this returns blank.  Not sure why I can't get it to work, because this seems like a pretty obvious issue.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't the regex code be part of your loop?

Comment: You're right.  It is in my code, I just made a mistake copying it over.  Just edited the question.

Comment: Did you make sure that the `htmltext` is not blank?

Comment: I didn't replicate your set up exactly but when I pulled out text from a file it prints "address" for each occurrence. I think your html text might be empty?

Comment: When I run Print Htmltext it prints out the source code so I don't think htmltext is coming up blank, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Why are you parsing the HTML with BeautifulSoup, only to ignore it and then try to chew through the HTML with a regex?  If you're looking for a tag attribute="value" pair, use a proper HTML parser, like the one you've already got.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code works. It's the regex that is failing you. Try this in the regex part of your code:

```
regex = "address(| )=(| )([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+)(\s+|$)"
for curMatch in re.finditer(regex, htmltext):
    print curMatch.group(3)
```

This will only print the url part. It's not perfect but you can find better regexes for matching urls with a quick search.